# Can I query foreign servers without creating foreign tables?

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I know that dblink can be queried directly like:

`select * from dblink('kenyon_dblink','select * from test') as  t1 (id integer,name varchar);`

I wonder if I can query foreign servers without creating foreign tables, since my query strings are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just open a dblink connection in the same session with [`dblink_connect()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/contrib-dblink-connect.html) (named or unnamed).

Example:

- [Is there any shortcut for using dblink in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828792/is-there-any-shortcut-for-using-dblink-in-postgres/7829413#7829413)

Example with dynamic SQL:

- [Syntax error in function using dblink to replicate new data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173125/syntax-error-in-function-using-dblink-to-replicate-new-data/31174066#31174066)

This works for connections between **PostgreSQL** DBs, not for other RDBMS. [Per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/dblink.html):

> dblink is a module that supports connections to other PostgreSQL
>   databases.

Comment: I created a foreign data wrapper and a foreign server to MS sql server. Can I query this foreign server directly without creating foreign tables?

Comment: I created a foreign data wrapper and a foreign server like this:

`create extension tds_fdw;

create server mssql_svr foreign data wrapper tds_fdw options (servername '127.0.0.1', port '1433', database 'testdb', tds_version '7.1');

create user mapping for postgres server mssql_svr options (username 'user', password 'passwd');`

Could you please give me an example how to query mssql_svr? Thanks!

Comment: @xiagao1982: Oh sorry, I missed that you just mentioned MS SQL Server in your comment (which must be in the question, really). [Per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/dblink.html)`: dblink is a module that supports connections to other PostgreSQL databases`.

Comment: So, you are saying that there is no way to query a table in sqlserver or oracle database without creating a foreign table? Really? They must gotta be kidding us!

Comment: @ChristianB.Almeida: How would Postgres know how to access foreign data? Would you know of *any* RDBMS that can access foreign tables in different RDBMS automatically? (I don't.) Consider starting a new *question* instead of discussing it in the comments here.

Comment: Look... I don't want to compare apples with oranges, but Oracle "database link" does it very well, whoever remote database is. What I am trying to say is that "fdw" is very burocratic and doesnt make any sense. I know it is not postgres developers fault... but it will be easier if we can just do: "select * from table@remotedatabase", and don't worry about anything else!

Comment: Sure would be a lot easier, but that seems like a hell of a task. Not sure major (proprietary) RDBMS would even be *willing* to cooperate.